# Aggregated sum of another column over a vector of names in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data.frame:

```
> DF <- data.frame(names = I(list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("a"), c("c", "d"))),
                   counts = c(1, 2, 3))
> DF
    names counts
1 a, b, c      1
2       a      2
3    c, d      3
```

How do I get a result that sums up the total counts of each name?
Something like:

```
name sum
a      3
b      1
c      4
d      3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 DF1 <- data.frame(name=unlist(DF$names),
          val=rep(DF$counts,sapply(DF$names, length)))
```

Or

```
 DF1 <- do.call(rbind,Map(data.frame, name=DF$names, val=DF$counts))

 aggregate(val~name, DF1, sum)
 #    name val
 #1    a   3
 #2    b   1
 #3    c   4
 #4    d   3
```

Or

```
  DF2 <- transform(stack(setNames(DF$names, DF$counts)),
                               ind=as.numeric(as.character(ind)))
  aggregate(ind~values, DF2, sum)
```

Comment: Is there any preference/advantage for each of the three ways you show above? The first method seems to most elementary/obvious and is easy to understand, although the second seems neat, too. The third does seem rather obscure to me, although.

Comment: @fnl All these functions are based on `base R`.  Regarding the `stack` approach.  If you name the `list` i.e. `DF$names` using `setNames`, and then apply `stack`, it will return the `key/value` pair in the long form, but the `ind` column would be `factor.  So, I converted that to `numeric` and then used `aggregate` to get the sum.

Comment: OK, thanks! One point, maybe: I did 10k replicates and measured performance. The first version took 2.792 sec, the second 8.591, and the last 5.541 sec using 10k replicates. If I then do it with my real data (155k/98k non-/unique names) this relation roughly holds, too. So the least obscure method is the fastest, too. Thanks for the explanation of the last one, always nice to learn something new!

Comment: @fnl Thanks for the benchmark. You could post that info in your post.